# Can I control the number of DPU in the AWS Glue Service?

Tags: aws-glue

Can I control the number of DPU in the AWS Glue Service?

I read in official documents that Glue has six of DPUs, but I don't need up to six DPUs.
In addition, I am afraid that there will be an excessive cost.

Comment: What you mean by control the number of DPUs? You want to use less than 6 DPUs? Could you please clarify your question

Comment: Yes, that's right. I want to use less then 6 DPUs : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimum DPUs required for your Glue job to run is two. You don't need six DPUs always to execute your Glue job.

To properly plan your capacity you ca refer to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-debug-capacity.html).

Answer (score 5):

You can specify number and type workers. A quote from [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/glue/latest/dg/add-job.html):

> **Worker type**
>
> The following worker types are available:
>
> - Standard – When you choose this type, you also provide a value for Maximum capacity. Maximum capacity is the number of AWS Glue data
>     processing units (DPUs) that can be allocated when this job runs. A
>     DPU is a relative measure of processing power that consists of 4 vCPUs
>     of compute capacity and 16 GB of memory. The Standard worker type has
>     a 50 GB disk and 2 executors.
> - G.1X – When you choose this type, you also provide a value for Number of workers. Each worker maps to 1 DPU (4 vCPU, 16 GB of memory,
>     64 GB disk), and provides 1 executor per worker. We recommend this
>     worker type for memory-intensive jobs.
> - G.2X – When you choose this type, you also provide a value for Number of workers. Each worker maps to 2 DPU (8 vCPU, 32 GB of memory,
>     128 GB disk), and provides 1 executor per worker. We recommend this
>     worker type for memory-intensive jobs and jobs that run ML transforms.
>
>   You are charged an hourly rate based on the number of DPUs used to run your ETL jobs. For more information, see the AWS Glue pricing page.
>
>   When you configure a job using the console and specify a Worker type of Standard, the Maximum capacity is set and the Number of
>     workers becomes the value of Maximum capacity - 1. If you use the AWS
>     Command Line Interface (AWS CLI) or AWS SDK, you can specify the Max
>     capacity parameter, or you can specify both Worker type and the Number
>     of workers. For more information, see Jobs.
>
> **Number of workers**
>
> The number of workers of a defined workerType that are allocated when a job runs.
>   With G.1X and G.2X Worker types, you must specify the number of workers of that type.
>   The maximum number of workers you can define are 299 for G.1X, and 149 for G.2X.